# почему пример на видео работает а у меня возникает ошибка

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

учусь писать код по видео курсу, в видео все работает, а у меня выходит ошибка.

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray jsonArray = new jsonObject.getJSONArray(s); //Cannot resolve symbol 'getJSONArray'

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lv;
String article, date;

//JSON string
private static String JSON_URL = "https://cms.zaonce.net/en-GB/jsonapi/node/galnet_article?sort=-created";

List<ArticleModelClass> articleList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    articleList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    GetData getData = new GetData();
    getData.execute();
}

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String current = "";
        try{
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try{
                url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                int data = isr.read();
                while(data != -1){
                    current += (char) data;
                    data = isr.read();
                }
                return current;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(urlConnection !=null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return current;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new jsonObject.getJSONArray(s);

            for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.lenght() ; i++){
                JSONOject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ArticleModelClass model = new ArticleModelClass();
                model.setArticle(jsonObject1.getSting("article"));
                model.setImg(jsonObject1.getString("img"));
                articleList.add(model);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<ArticleModelClass>articleList);
    }
}

private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<ArticleModelClass>articleList){
    Adaptery adaptery = new Adaptery(this, articleList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptery);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new jsonObject.getJSONArray(s);
                       ^----- Проблема тутЬ
```

слово `new` тут лишнее

Comment: Спасибо, помогло